# Problema con lectura de xml con estructura extraña

Tags: javascript, xml

Con el código de más abajo estoy leyendo un xml con una estructura dada para volcar  los datos en una taba de 3 columnas (Nombre, Ubicacion, Beneficio).
El xml lo carga bien, pero cuando quiero llegar a los datos con `getElementsByTagName`, no puedo llegar a ellos, me aparece por cada dato en el listado de las tablas `object HTMLCollection]`.

Muchísima gracias de antemano.

¡Saludos y que estén muy bien!

Este es el codijo JS y XML

```
let xmlContent = '';
    let tableinscritos = document.getElementById('losinscritos');
    fetch('inscritos.xml').then((response)=> {
        response.text().then((xml)=>{
            xmlContent = xml;

            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(xmlContent, 'application/xml');
            let dinscritos = xmlDOM.querySelectorAll('inscrito');

            dinscritos.forEach(bookXmlNode => {

                let row = document.createElement('tr');

                //inscrito
                let td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = td.innerText = bookXmlNode.getElementsByTagName ("nombre");
                row.appendChild(td);
                console.log(`ver ${td.innerText}`)

                //  ubicación
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = bookXmlNode.getElementsByTagName ("ubicacion");
                row.appendChild(td);

                //  beneficio
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = bookXmlNode.getElementsByTagName ("beneficio");
                row.appendChild(td);
                

                tableinscritos.children[1].appendChild(row);
                
            });
            
        });
    }); 
    
    /*ESTE ES EL XML
    <lista>
    <inscrito id="uno">
        <nombre>Inscrito Uno</nombre>
        <ubicacion>Mi Hogar Uno</ubicacion>
        <beneficio>Beneficio Total Uno</beneficio>
    </inscrito>

        <inscrito id="uno">
        <nombre>Inscrito Dos</nombre>
        <ubicacion>Mi Hogar Dos</ubicacion>
        <beneficio>Beneficio Total Dos</beneficio>
    </inscrito>
    

        <inscrito id="uno">
        <nombre>Inscrito Tres</nombre>
        <ubicacion>Mi Hogar Tres</ubicacion>
        <beneficio>Beneficio Total Tres</beneficio>
    </inscrito>
</lista>
    
 */
```

Comment: Prueba usando `xmlDOM.querySelector('nombre')`. Aunque cada inscrito tenga solo una tupla de atributos, `getElementsByTagName` siempre devuelve HTMLCollection tal como `querySelectorAll` siempre devuelve NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

Muchísimas gracias!!

pero ahora lamentablemente  me cambiaron  la estructura Xml que estoy leyendo; son los mismos datos pero ahora con la estructura de código de más abajo.

Por lo tanto, modifiqué el JS, y me pinta los datos en el html, pero sólo los de  la primera línea del  xml.

Hice un console.log  para ver el largo de “books” y claro, me da 1, me imagino que es por eso que solo pinta sólo la primera linea (creo ). Pero no he podido encontrar el por qué.

Según las personas que me pasan la estructura xml, ésta funciona por que la han usado desde hace tiempo.

Por favor, me pueden dar alguna luz.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Saludos y que estén muy bien

Este es el código que hice:

```
<script>
    let xmlContent = '';
    let tableBooks = document.getElementById('losinscritos');
    fetch('inscritos_atrib.xml').then((response)=> {
        response.text().then((xml)=>{
            xmlContent = xml;
     
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(xmlContent, 'text/xml');
            let books = xmlDOM.querySelectorAll('datos');
            books.forEach(bookXmlNode => {
                console.log(`LARGO = ${books.length}`)
                let row = document.createElement('tr');
                //inscrito
                let td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = td.innerText = bookXmlNode.getElementsByTagName("dato")[0].getAttribute("nombre");
                row.appendChild(td);
                console.log(`ver ${td.innerText}`)
                //  ubicación
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = bookXmlNode.getElementsByTagName("dato")[0].getAttribute("ubicacion");
                row.appendChild(td);
                //  beneficio
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = bookXmlNode.getElementsByTagName("dato")[0].getAttribute("beneficio");
                row.appendChild(td);
                tableBooks.appendChild(row);
             });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <!--ESTE ES EL XML AHORA
    <datos>
    <dato nombre="Inscrito Uno" ubicacion="Mi Hogar Uno" beneficio="Beneficio Total Uno"/>
    <dato nombre="Inscrito Dos" ubicacion="Mi Hogar Dos" beneficio="Beneficio Total Dos"/>
    <dato nombre="Inscrito Tres" ubicacion="Mi Hogar Tres" beneficio="Beneficio Total Tres"/>
    </datos>

    -->
```

Answer (score 0):

te simplifico la vida usa jquery para iterar por el Xml y la tabla ponla en texto y luego le das append a la tabla en el HTML.

```js
let xml = `<datos>
                <dato nombre="Inscrito Uno" ubicacion="Mi Hogar Uno" beneficio="Beneficio Total Uno"/>
                <dato nombre="Inscrito Dos" ubicacion="Mi Hogar Dos" beneficio="Beneficio Total Dos"/>
                <dato nombre="Inscrito Tres" ubicacion="Mi Hogar Tres" beneficio="Beneficio Total Tres"/>
                </datos>`;

    parser = new DOMParser();
    XmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

    let table = '';
    $(XmlDoc).find('dato').each(function () {

        table += `<tr>
                    <td>${$(this).attr('nombre')}</td>
                    <td>${$(this).attr('ubicacion')}</td>
                    <td>${$(this).attr('beneficio')}</td>
                 </tr>`;

    });

    $("#Tabla tbody").append(table);
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table" id="Tabla">
        <thead>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Ubicación</th>
            <th>Beneficio</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```